# Use text field with multiple values with , in SOQL where clause

Tags: apex, soql

I have customobject with groups__c text field which hold id of different public groups Id with ","

`groups__c = 0011U00000oyv2AQAQ,0011U00000oyv2BQAQ`

I'm using this field in where clause

```
List<String> groupIds = new List<String>();
for(GroupMember gm :[SELECT Id,GroupId,UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE UserOrGroupId = :userId]){
    groupIds.add(gm.GroupId);
}

for(CustomObj__c obj : [SELECT Id, Name FROM CustomObj__c where groups__c IN :groupIds])
```

here it returns records of CustomObj__c for only **0011U00000oyv2AQAQ** UserOrGroupId

Is it possible to query so that it will return for all mention groupIds in groups__c field?

Comment: have you considered normalizing the DB so you don't have to save multiple IDs in one field? What you want to do is incredibly hard for how simple the request is.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your suggestion? As per my reqirement we have specific record on custom object which I want to pull in Flow. This record should only available to users who are part of perticular public group. so if Record A have 3 public group id saved in field, that record pulled for that public group user when he runs flow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `where groups__c IN :groupIds` will only return against hard matches of each single value, instead of checking against a `LIKE` operator. Simply change your `groupIds.add(gm.GroupId);` line to `groupIds.add('%' + gm.GroupId + '%');`, and your `IN` clause to a `LIKE`, and it should function as you expect.

```
List<String> groupIds = new List<String>();
for(GroupMember gm :[SELECT Id,GroupId,UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE UserOrGroupId = :userId]){
    groupIds.add('%' + gm.GroupId + '%');
}

for(CustomObj__c obj : [SELECT Id, Name FROM CustomObj__c where groups__c LIKE :groupIds])
```

Comment: I don't think I ever tried this, but can you use a List against a `LIKE` comparator?

Comment: @SebastianKessel You absolutely can. :)

Comment: I just learned something new

Comment: @DrewKennedy Thank you so much for answer. I'm still confused on ```groupIds.add('%' + gm.GroupId + '%');``` part, I'll try system.debug to see output of groupIds if that make sense to me.

Comment: @Ghosty With the LIKE clause you can use `%` to act as a wildcard. `'%' + gm.GroupId` would represent `ends with`, `gm.GroupId + '%' ` would represent `starts with` and `'%' + gm.GroupId + '%'` respresents `contains`.